# How to create a 3D fill-between plot from an array

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d, pythonplotter

I have a 3D matrix from simulating four random variables during 6 hours 2000 times:

```
# Display the shape of the matrix_outputs array
print(matrix_outputs.shape)
(2000, 86400, 4)
```

the first term is the number of running from the simulation, the second term is the number of samples, and the last one is the number of variables generated (estimated load, estimated energy to harvest, real load, and real renewable harvested).

Plotting the first run I have:

[image: First 6-hours run of the four variables]

The code I used for plotting it:

```
    # Define time
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        t = np.arange(0, max_sim/(60/0.25), 1/(60/0.25))  # Define time in minutes using the 'max_sim'
    
    # Create a plot
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
    fig.set_size_inches(10, 5)
    ax.fill_between(t, matrix_outputs[0,:,0], facecolor='C0', alpha=0.4)
    ax.fill_between(t, matrix_outputs[0,:,1], facecolor='C1', alpha=0.4)
    ax.fill_between(t, matrix_outputs[0,:,2], facecolor='C2', alpha=0.4)
    ax.fill_between(t, matrix_outputs[0,:,3], facecolor='C3', alpha=0.4)
```

I want to plot something as the following image:

[image: 2D bar graphs in different planes]

With the axis to be:

[image: Axes as I need them]

So far I have

```
# Define time
t = np.arange(0, max_sim/(60/0.25), 1/(60/0.25))  # Define time in minutes using the 'max_sim'

# Create a 3D plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

# Set labels for the axes
ax.set_xlabel('Time (minutes)')  # Set the x-axis label to represent time
ax.set_ylabel('Run ID')
ax.set_zlabel('Random Variable Output')

# Plot the data points using time 't', number run, and random outputs
ax.plot(t, matrix_outputs[0,:,0], matrix_outputs[:,0,0],zdir='y')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

But I don't know how to implement each number to make a 3D plot. Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can try this sample to create your 3D chart.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))

axl = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
for z in np.arange(0, 40, 10):
    x = np.arange(20)
    y = np.random.randn(20)
    axl.bar(x, y, zs=z, zdir='y')

axl.set_xlabel('x', fontsize=15)
axl.set_ylabel('y', fontsize=15)
axl.set_zlabel('z', fontsize=15)
plt.show()
```